# Why does IIS Express shut down the Application and restart it all the time?

Tags: c#, iis, visual-studio-2013, iis-express

I'm debugging an application in Visual Studio 2013 and IIS Express. I noticed that certain cache values and static variables are lost all the time. To investigate it, I put breakpoints into `global.asax`'s `Application_Start` and `Application_End`, and I saw that they frequently get fired.

Is there any way to see the reason of a `Application_End` event in IIS Express?

**EDIT:** To be clear, the `Application_Start` and `Application_End` events are fired multiple times in the same debugging session. The breakpoints in these events are hit multiple times without me stopping or restarting the debug session.

Comment: Are you writing to files in \bin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. My code lives in the Dropbox folder, and apparently Dropbox changes something inside the web project's bin folder.

When I deactivate Dropbox, the problem goes away.

Answer (score 3):

IIS Express is designed to emulate IIS for development purpose, it is provided with Visual Studio 2012, and 2013.

> Is there any way to see the reason of a Application_End event in IIS
>   Express?

Since it is used for development, it starts when a web project is executed in Visual studio and stops when it terminates.

See: [Web Servers in Visual Studio for ASP.NET Web Projects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58wxa9w5.aspx)

> IIS Express **starts automatically when you run a project in Visual
>   Studio, and it stops when you close the web site project** or web
>   application project in Visual Studio.

EDIT:

To address your edit in question, make sure you are not modifying `web.config` or creating/modifying any files in application folder *(bin)*. This could cause the application to restart.

Comment: @cheeesus, Are you modifying your web.config by any chance ?  or writing to files/folders in the application directory ?That could cause application to restart, other than that, I am not sure. You could try hosting your application in your local IIS, and put some logging in Application_start and end events to see if they are being hit multiple times.

Comment: No, I'm not changing anything. I have found that the restarts even happen while there are no requests hitting IIS Express

Comment: I have this exact same issue. Nothing is being written (and not like @cheeesus indicated in dropbox - just constant restarts)